# Adjusting SRC field for image in IE8 using JQuery causes Stack Overflow error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, stack-overflow

I needed to add lazy loading to my Twitter Bootstrap slider and I came across [this](http://www.maurizioconventi.com/2012/06/12/how-to-create-a-lazy-load-carousel-with-twitter-bootstrap/)

It works fine in all browsers however in native IE8 it comes up with "Stack overflow at line: 0" when the slider tries to change the src attribute to the lazy-src attribute.

I've tried doing straight Javascript getelementbyid adjustments to no avail, I've tried having an image already defined and just updating it, but it still happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same for me except I'm using jquery cycle plugin as my image slider and I added lazy loading to it as well. Only happens in IE8.